# What does "wrinkle" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a *[Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-00340-6)* article about generative AI tools, like Chatgpt, the author was discussing the legal statue of these tools:

> A further confusion is the legal status of some LLMs, which were trained on content scraped from the Internet with sometimes less-than-clear permissions. Copyright and licensing laws currently cover direct copies of pixels, text and software, but not imitations in their style. When those imitations — generated through AI — are trained by ingesting the originals, this introduces **a wrinkle**.

What does "wrinkle" mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Wrinkle' here is an example of a type of figure of speech called a ***metaphor***.

> metaphor
>
> noun
>
> an expression, often found in literature, that describes a person or
> object by referring to something that is considered to have similar
> characteristics to that person or object:
>
> "The mind is an ocean" and "the city is a jungle" are both metaphors.

[Metaphor (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/metaphor)

Literally, a wrinkle is a small line or fold in (e.g.) a piece of cloth that was formerly smooth and even.

Figuratively, if a process or set of arrangements, that formerly worked well, now has a new issue or problem, that could be called a 'wrinkle'. The new problem is the uncertain legal status of AI-generated imitations of original works of art.

Comment: Also found in daily life. Every term used for computing, for instance, is a metaphor of something that preceded computers: _file, print, command, program, application, disk, drive, ..._ See Lakoff and Johnson for more. As for _wrinkle_, that just means a small 3-dimensional flaw in a two-dimensional thing; if the 2-D thing is a plan on paper, a wrinkle means a problem in the plan.